# confuse methods in association class diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram

[image]

I have above class diagram. I am very confused on whether the above product methods should place in Product class or the user class. If I am right in my diagram, so I should only place product's setters and getters method on it?

Comment: Just a quick note - apparently you duplicate the same information. Your attribute products on NormalUser is probably the same thing as what you've presented by a composite aggregation. According to the UML specification inline attribute and association drawn as a line have the same semantical meaning (with possibility to provide more details in case of attribute like aggregationKind or relationship navigability). Thus on aggregation on Product end you should put a role `products` and you should remove the inline version of the attribute from NormalUser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your approach with placing the addProduct, deleteProduct etc on NormalUser is correct.

You might still have for example edit operation on Product to handle calls from (for example) NormalUser depending on your functionality/project/design/... .

Also don't use getters and setters (or at least make them private) unless you really know what you're doing. Providing public accessors to all attributes works in (almost) exactly the same way as making all attributes public effectively breaking the principle of hermetization/encapsulation.